# useEffect() not being called when i refresh a certain page

Tags: session, react-hooks, supabase

I'm using supabase to get a user session and updating the "Sign In" "Sign out" button whenever a user is logged in. If a user session exists, I set the usersession state to true and the button should be "Sign Out". If it doesn't exist, it means that a user is not signed in and the button should be "Sign In."

I make sure that the session data is loaded by using a "Loading" display, and this works for all other pages but just one page, "localhost:3000/course". Whenever I refresh in this page, the "Sign Out" button gets stuck on "Loading" and it never calls the useEffect().

```
export function SiteHeader() {
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>()
  const router = useRouter()
  const [usersession, setUser] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const handleSignOut = async () => {
    if (usersession) {
      const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut()
      if (!error) {
        // Update the state to indicate that the user is signed out
        setUser(false)
        router.refresh()
      } else {
        // Handle sign-out error, if any
        console.error("Error signing out:", error)
      }
    } else {
      console.log("user is not logged in")
      // If user data is null, handle sign in logic here
      router.push("/authentication")
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect is called")
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        const {
          data: { session },
        } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
        if (session?.user) {
          setUser(true)
        } else {
          setUser(false)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching session:", error)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false) 
      }
    }

    fetchUser()
  })


  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 z-40 w-full border-b bg-background">
      <div className="container flex items-center h-16 space-x-4 sm:justify-between sm:space-x-0">
        <MainNav items={siteConfig.mainNav} />
        <div className="flex items-center justify-end flex-1 space-x-4">
          <nav className="flex items-center space-x-1">
            <Button
              onClick={async () => {
                handleSignOut()
              }}
            >
              {loading ? "Loading..." : usersession ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In"}
            </Button>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

- for the "/course" page, you first have to be logged in to access it. could this maybe interfere with getting the usersession from useEffect()?

```
const CourseHomePage = async () => {
  const session = await getSession()

  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>()
  let supabase_data
  if (session) {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("payment")
      .select()
      .eq("created_by", session?.user.id)
      .eq("is_success", true)
    supabase_data = data
  }

  if (!session) {
    return redirect("/authentication")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the missing `[]` at the end of `useEffect`?

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect is called")
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        const {
          data: { session },
        } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
        if (session?.user) {
          setUser(true)
        } else {
          setUser(false)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching session:", error)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false) 
      }
    }

    fetchUser()
  }, [])
```